# How do I add test dependencies to a module in JDK 9 for IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-9

I am building a project with maven 3.3.9 using java 9 (build 9-ea+165). Tests ran and build were successful.

However. IntelliJ Idea 2017.1.2 is complaining and will not compile/run tests with the message 'The module  does not have the module 'junit.jupiter.api' in its requirements.

How do I add this for IntelliJ?
Is it necessary?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot from editor in IntelliJ.]

Project structure:
[image: Project structure]

From pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>4.12.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: please share the exact message or a screenshot of the message, also what test dependencies are you using if any?

Comment: Have you tried it with java 8? Is that possible with your source? Maybe just to check if it fixes the dependencies in the test even if it can't compile and run your code

Comment: Have you checked that the relevant jars are available in your maven cache? Usually ~/.m2/repository/...

Comment: Can you check that there is a relevant entry in the dependency management section for each of those libs and that it has an ok version?

Comment: When IntelliJ runs your tests it'll probably output the command it used -- including the classpath -- at the top of the console. Check that to see if the jars you need are actually on the classpath, in the right order.

Comment: deendency management: i forgot to add the managed versions but this seems not to be the problem versions:

        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <org.hamcrest.version>1.3</org.hamcrest.version>
        <org.junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M4</org.junit.jupiter.version>
        <org.mockito.version>2.7.22</org.mockito.version>

Comment: the project has many modules and many dependencies... i have created a small poc to recreate the problem on GitHub. i am experiencing almost the same - this project does not build with maven either :(. please take a look at the branch jigsaw-poc-wip on https://github.com/jactor-rises/junit-poc/branches

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your project structure isn't valid anymore. You can try to check if your folder containing your tests is your actual test folder:

1. Press [Ctrl] [Alt] [Shift] [S] to open Project Structure.
2. Open "Modules"
3. Open the "Sources tab"
4. Your folder containing the tests should be marked as "Tests" (the icon will be green)

Comment: the project structure is fine, Joost Verbraeken. the folder src/main/java is blue and marked as Source Folders and src/test/java is green and  marked as Test Source Folders...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options

First, you may not have imported the project correctly into IntelliJ in the first place. In which case the quickest thing to do is often to simply close the project, remove the intellij files from the source directory (`.idea` directories and any `*.i?l` files), and reopen the appropriate root pom file, using the `open` option (if it gives you the option, choose to create a new project and delete the old project).

Second option is that you have correctly opened the project but you've not reimported it since changing the pom and you don't have autoimport switched on and you ignored the notifications asking you to reload. In which case just open the maven window (usually from a horizontal button on the right of the screen) and hit the reimport button at the top left of the maven window.

The third option is to blow away your caches. This is easily done from the file menu.

There may be others. I'd start from the bottom up.

Comment: First: I have closed the project. Removed .idea folder and removed any *.i?l file. Imported the project ones more using the root pom of the project... But no cigar :( ... Second and third: I have refreshed all maven projects, and also tried to invalidate my caches and restarted IntelliJ, but still no cigar... :( I did not think that the second and third option should help in any way, since I am unable to import the project in the first place...